# Tengo un error "crosses initialization of 'jugador p3' al usar el switch en C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
class jugador{
    char *nombre;
    float arg;
    char *equipo;
    int aux;

    public:
        jugador(char *, char *, float);
       ~jugador();
        jugador(jugador &j);
        char *getnombre();
        char *getequipo();
        float getarg();
        void setnombre(char *n);
        void setequipo(char *e);
        void setarg(float a);
        void operator=(jugador &p)
        {
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"sobrecarga del operador"<<endl;
            aux=p.aux;
            nombre=new char[aux+1];
            strcpy(nombre,p.nombre);
            aux=p.aux;
            equipo=new char[aux+1];
            strcpy(equipo,p.equipo);
            arg=p.arg;
            }
            void mostrar_jugador();
};
jugador::jugador(char *n,char *e, float a){
    aux= ::strlen(n);
    nombre=new char[aux+1];
    strcpy(nombre, n);
    aux= ::strlen(n);
    equipo=new char[aux+1];
    strcpy( equipo, e);
    arg=a;
}
jugador::jugador(jugador &j){
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"constructor copia"<<endl;
    aux=j.aux;
    nombre=new char[aux+1];
    strcpy(nombre,j.nombre);
    cout<<"se creo la copia de la clase para "<<nombre<<endl;
    aux=j.aux;
    equipo=new char[aux+1];
    strcpy(equipo,j.equipo);
    cout<<"se creo la copia de la clase para "<<equipo<<endl;
    arg=j.arg;
}
void jugador::mostrar_jugador(){
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Equipo: "<<equipo<<endl;
    cout<<"Arg: "<<arg<<endl;
    }
jugador::~jugador(){
}
main(){ 
    int op;
    cout<<"1.Ingreso de 3 jugadores"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Crear copia de los 3 jugadores"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Mostrar a los jugadores"<<endl;
    cout<<"4.Mostrar mejor jugador"<<endl;
    cout<<"5.salir"<<endl;
    cout<<"----Elija una opcion----"<<endl;
    cin>>op;
switch(op){
    case 1:
    jugador p((char*)"Edwin", (char*)"Tigres", 20 );
    jugador p2((char*)"Maria", (char*)"Rapidos", 21 );
    jugador p3((char*)"Julio", (char*)"Triunfadores", 30 );
        break;
    case 2://aquí empieza el problema no se porque
    jugador x1(p);
        x1.mostrar_jugador();
    jugador x2(p2);
        x2.mostrar_jugador();
    jugador x3(p3);
        x3.mostrar_jugador();
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    case 4:
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"Opcion invalida"<<endl;
}   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Los bloques `switch` son diferentes a los bloques `if-else` por varios motivos:

- El compilador tiene mayor margen de libertad para aplicar optimizaciones.
- Las etiquetas `case` no tienen ámbito propio.

Para evitar la aparición de incongruencias y errores difíciles de encontrar debido a la segunda característica, dentro de cada `case` **no se deben** declarar variables. Estas podrían colisionar con las variables de otro `case` y su ciclo de vida no es sencillo de acotar.

Para poder declarar variables dentro de un `case` es necesario crear un ámbito, lo cual se consigue con las llaves `{ }`. Ahora bien, si revisamos tu código:

```
switch(op){
  case 1:
    jugador p((char*)"Edwin", (char*)"Tigres", 20 );
    jugador p2((char*)"Maria", (char*)"Rapidos", 21 );
    jugador p3((char*)"Julio", (char*)"Triunfadores", 30 );
    break;
  case 2://aquí empieza el problema no se porque
    jugador x1(p);
    x1.mostrar_jugador();
    jugador x2(p2);
    x2.mostrar_jugador();
    jugador x3(p3);
    x3.mostrar_jugador();
    break;
```

Vemos que estás declarando variables en el `case 1` que luego intentas reutilizar en el `case 2`... pero claro si `op==2` es imposible que `op==1`. Dicho de otra manera: si se ejecuta el `case 2` no se va a ejecutar el `case 1`, luego las variables `p`, `p2` y `p3` no van a estar ni declaradas ni inicializadas y eso no se arregla ni tan siquiera con las llaves.

Para verlo mejor vamos a refactorizar ligeramente el código:

```
void func1()
{
  // variables locales
  jugador p((char*)"Edwin", (char*)"Tigres", 20 );
  jugador p2((char*)"Maria", (char*)"Rapidos", 21 );
  jugador p3((char*)"Julio", (char*)"Triunfadores", 30 );
}

void func2()
{
  jugador x1(p); // ¿Que es p?
  x1.mostrar_jugador();
  jugador x2(p2); // ¿Que es p2?
  x2.mostrar_jugador();
  jugador x3(p3); // ¿Que es p3?
  x3.mostrar_jugador();
}

// ...

if( op == 1 )
  func1();
else if( op == 2 )
  func2();
```

Tu programa tiene que pedir los datos de 3 jugadores en la opción 1... y esos datos deben seguir vivos en sucesivas opciones, luego deberías mover su declaración al nivel del `main`.

Llegados a este punto tienes un problema y es que el constructor por defecto no está implementado. Esto te impide crear objetos sin valores específicos. Lo puedes solucionar usando punteros o habilitando el constructor por defecto. Lo más sencillo es habilitar el constructor por defecto (considera usar `std::string` en vez de `char*` al programar en C++).

```
class jugador
{
  std::string nombre;

public:
  // C++11 en adelante
  jugador() = default; 

  // Standares antiguos C++
  jugador()
  { }
};

int main(){ // <-- el tipo de retorno es obligatorio en C++
  jugador p, p2, p3;
```

Aunque, como hemos dicho, también se pueden usar punteros e ignorar el constructor por defecto:

- opción C++11, C++14, C++17

  ```
  int main() {

    std::unique_ptr<jugador> p, p1, p2;

    // ...
    switch(op)
    {
      case 1:
        // C++11 en adelante
        p.reset(new jugador("Edwin","Tigres",20));
        p2.reset(new jugador("Maria","Rapidos",21));
        p2.reset(new jugador("Julio","Triunfadores",30));

        // C++14 o C++17
        p = std::make_unique<jugador>("Edwin","Tigres",20);
        p2 = std::make_unique<jugador>("Maria","Rapidos",21);
        p2 = std::make_unique<jugador>("Julio","Triunfadores",30);

        break;

      case 2:
      { // iniciamos ambito para declarar variables
        // Hay que comprobar que los punteros estan inicializados
        if( p && p2 && p3 )
        {
          jugador x1(*p); // p es un puntero
          jugador x2(*p2);
          jugador x3(*p3);

          x1.mostrar_jugador();
          x2.mostrar_jugador();
          x3.mostrar_jugador();
        }
        else
          std::cout << "No se han introducido datos\n";

        break;
      }
    }

    // ...
    // No es necesario borrar los punteros, se borran solos
  }
  ```
- opcion C++98, C++03 (versiones antiguas)

  ```
  int main() {

    jugador *p = 0, *p1 = 0, *p2 = 0;

    // ...
    switch(op)
    {
      case 1:
        p = new jugador("Edwin","Tigres",20);
        p2 = new jugador("Maria","Rapidos",21);
        p2 = new jugador("Julio","Triunfadores",30);

        break;

      case 2:
      {
        // Hay que comprobar que los punteros estan inicializados
        if( p && p2 && p3 )
        {
          jugador x1(*p);
          jugador x2(*p2);
          jugador x3(*p3);

          x1.mostrar_jugador();
          x2.mostrar_jugador();
          x3.mostrar_jugador();
        }
        else
          std::cout << "No se han introducido datos\n";

        break;
      }
    }

    // ...

    delete p;
    delete p2;
    delete p3;
  }
  ```

**Nota final**

Te he comentado que es preferible sustituir `char*` por `std::string`. Te lo digo porque el uso que haces de los punteros en C++ es incorrecto:

```
jugador p((char*)"Edwin", (char*)"Tigres", 20 );
//        ^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^
```

Esas dos conversiones te están chivando que estás intentando hacer algo peligroso en C++. Las cadenas escritas *a pelo* son, por definición, constantes. Modificar una de estas cadenas puede resultar en un comportamiento indefinido de la aplicación (puede no pasar nada o que las cadenas se almacenen en memoria de solo lectura y el Sistema Operativo mate tu aplicación), eso sin contar con que puedes acabar pisando memoria de otras variables:

```
char* cad = (char*)"a"; // cad apunta a un array de 2 bytes
strcpy(cad,"ABCDE");    // ¿Donde metemos los 3 bytes de mas?
```

Las soluciones estilo C pasarían entonces por usar memoria dinámica para gestionar las cadenas o usar un array de tamaño fijo (`nombre[100]`) y pegarte con la gestión de punteros y la copia de cadenas *a mano* con `strcpy` y compañía.

Sin embargo la solución C++ pasa por usar la clase `std::string`:

```
std::string cadena = "a"; // ok
cadena = "ABCDE"; // ok, la clase se encarga de gestionar la memoria del
```

Comment: gracias es una respuesta muy útil a decir verdad es una respuesta muy buena que no esperaba muchas gracias por tus consejos